# Selecting groups within variable that meet count criteria

Tags: sas

I have a variable with groups, we'll say they are colors.  I need to select only the colors with 5-10 observations. I will then be performing a test on each of those groups. How can I go about doing this?

I am using SAS University Edition.

Comment: This isn't appropriate for a Stack Overflow question.  Please make an attempt to solve the problem and ask questions about that.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this specifically using a SAS program?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand why this is not appropriate.  I am using SAS University.  I am able to perform my test by groupings (proc sort by grouping), but I need to select only the groups that have, say, 5-10 observations. I searched all day yesterday to figure this out but I cannot find anything to help me short of creating a new data set for each group.

Comment: The question is inappropriate because you're not asking a programming question, as far as I can tell.  If you are, then you're not asking one that is sufficiently specific - this site isn't for asking someone to write a large program for you, this is for answering narrow, specific programming questions.  See the [faq] and the [help] for more information.

Comment: If you're asking for help with the point-and-click elements of SAS University edition, then you need to go ask that question at an appropriate site - such as [communities.sas.com](http://communities.sas.com).  This is only for the programming side of things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you mean that you have a variable that DEFINES groups, such as a variable named COLOR with values like 'RED' and 'GREEN'.  Then if you want to select only the observations for groups that have at least 5 observations you will have to count the number of observations per group.

Since you didn't post any sample data let's use SASHELP.CLASS which has a variable SEX that can be used to group into the 9 female and 10 male students.  So let's write a query to only return the groups with at least 10 observations (the male students).

This is very is easy to do with PROC SQL using a GROUP BY and a HAVING clause.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select * from sashelp.class
  group by sex
  having count(*) > 9 
  ;
quit;
```

Note that this works well in SAS, but might not work in other SQL implementations.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is incredibly helpful. I have not used HAVING. I will explore this more. The only thing that came to mind was IF THEN or WHERE, but that wont work.  I will then need to take each of these groups and perform a Spearman Rank test, but one thing at a time. :)  Thank you again for your patient help.

Comment: You should be able to do that using PROC CORR. Use a BY statement to run separate analysis for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Tom.  I totally wasn't thinking about working with the new table I just created. It's been a while.  Just wanted to follow up with what I did:

```
     PROC SORT data=SPEAR.MAN;
      by var1;
     RUN;

     PROC SQL;
       CREATE table COUNT as select * from SPEAR.MAN
       GROUP by var1 having count (*) ge 5;
     QUIT;

     PROC CORR data=WORK.COUNT spearman nosimple;
       var var2 var3;
       by var1;
      RUN;
```

Comment: That should work.  Note that right now SAS will create the output data ordered  by the GROUP BY variables but per the documentation it is possible that will change in the future.  It is better to include an explicit ORDER BY clause if you are going to depend on the order, such as you are doing in the last step with the BY statement.

Answer (score -1):

You can alternatively do this with `proc sql`. The below method will allow you to keep all observations, but give you the flexibility to apply filters as needed within your procedures.

```
have
_________________
grouping y1 x1 x2 
1        5  10 20
1        6  20 40
2        7  30 60
2        4  40 0
2        6  50 1
_________________

proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
         select t1.grouping, y1, x1, x2, nobs
         from have as t1
         LEFT JOIN
              (select grouping, count(y1) as nobs
               from have
               group by grouping) as t2
         ON t1.grouping= t2.grouping
         order by t1.grouping
    ;
quit;
```

This will give you a dataset that looks as such:

```
want
______________________
grouping y1 x1 x2 nobs
1        5  10 20 2
1        6  20 40 2
2        7  30 60 3
2        4  40 0  3
2        6  50 1  3
```

You can now apply a filter using the new variable `nobs` on this dataset using whichever `proc` you would like to use. For example:

```
proc glm data=want;
    where nobs between 5 and 10;
    class grouping;
    model y1 = x1 x2;
run;
```